# error when building jquantlib with maven

Tags: java, maven, build, quantlib

I tried installin jquantlib by following the instructions in http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/JQuantLib_Users_Guide#Building_JQuantLib_from_command_line
However, I get the following errors when I run "mvn clean install" in the jquantlib-all folder. This is after I run "mvn clean install" in the jquantlib-parent folder btw and that worked fine. Has anyone else run into this before or tried to fix it? I tried reading the articles that the error message suggested but I couldn't get much help out of them.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project jquantlib: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/harish/workspace/jquantlib/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :jquantlib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message tells you that there a unit test failures and therefore the build has been stopped. You could try to skip the execution of the test suite by running:

```
mvn -DskipTests clean install
```